# Problem getting appointment with the Italian online visa booking system

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

I am trying to get an appointment for a Schengen visa from the Italian embassy's Dublin office online booking system.

https://ambdublino.esteri.it/ambasciata_dublino/it/informazioni_e_servizi/visti#BOOKING

I am getting the following error all the time:

> Unable to book an appointment. Exceeded maximum number of requests.

I tried emailing them but it looks like nobody is responding. Has anyone faced a similar situation?

Comment: It is very likely a queued system, first in, first allotted. With only a certain number of appointments available on any given day, it would mean that all were taken before your 'request' hit the server.

Comment: yes, but I tried multiple times. I checked the time slot for which I was trying and it was available in subsequent tries also.

Comment: They come out at specific times on specific days and you have to be quick to book it. Italian consulates are notorious for not being very efficient and booked up.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely a queued system, first in, first allotted. With only a certain number of appointments available on any given day, it would mean that all were taken before your 'request' hit the server.

Anecdotal feedback suggests that this is not uncommon with the Prenota online appointment system. Apparently, about 10-12 appointments are released per day, so it may take some persistance, timing and tactics (e.g., multiple concurrent browsers).

As example, Prenota New York suggests that

> In order to book an appointment with this visa office, we urge all our applicants, who could not find any availability, to repeatedly revisit our online appointment system since cancellations are quite regular. Please, be aware that the best time to check for appointment availability is after 6pm on.